# Rewrite this ajax code?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I do have a ajax code will work on a click of button. but I need it should automatically load function in between every 10 seconds. how can I rewrite below code??

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ajax with jQuery Example</title>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#generate").click(function(){
      $("#quote p").load("script.php");
    });
  });
  </script>
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
      width: 240px;
      height: 80px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="quote"><p> </p></div>
    <input type="submit" id="generate" value="Generate!">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $("#quote p").load("script.php");
  }, 10000);
});
```

This will call `$("#quote p").load("script.php")` (or more accurately, the anonymous function that contains this call) every 10 seconds (the second argument to [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) is specified in milliseconds).

Comment: great thanks...and by the by just out of the box question..are you from Kerala??

Comment: @john Yep, I am :) Was it my last name that gave it away?

Comment: @john Haha, short for John Abraham? Yeah my family name has some [historicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paliath_Achan) associated with it so that's probably why it's familiar!

Comment: this script gives a blank screen for 10 seconds..how can I get rid of??

Comment: You can make the first call explicitly without the interval and then use `setInterval` for subsequent calls.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $("#quote p").load("script.php");
}, 10000);
```

Which will load script.php every 10 seconds into `$('#quote p')`.